# Getting a column of table using another table

Tags: sql, database

I've question to ask.

Let's say I 've 2 database table.

```
Table1          Table2
------          ------

id(PK)          id(FK)

column2         column2

column3         column3
```

What I need is to write 1 query so I can take Table1's column2 using Table2's id(FK).
How can I do this with just one query?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to `JOIN` the tables.

```
select t1.column2
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
   on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

check this:

```
select column2  
from table1 t1 
where t1.id in (select t2.id 
                from tabel2 t2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are looking for is called a join. Find more on this e.g. in Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

It is not clear to me how your desired result should look like, so I cannot say for sure what your SQL statement would look like. Maybe an example with more concrete data would help?